# Spring Rest endpoint with identical urls

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Using Spring Rest I have two controller methods rest endpoints with following urls:

```
 @PutMapping("/book/delete")

 @PutMapping("/book/{action}")
```

My question is what happens if client sends the value for {action} "delete" on the second call? which of my spring mvc methods called? I tried and Spring succesfuly matched it to second url (while using swagger ui)

But I am not convinced that how can this happen, because from Servlet containers perspective they are equalivent resource paths. How spring knows where I am trying to access? Some answers claim that Spring chooses the more specific url with fewer wilcards. But couldn't find an official documentation.

Comment: The answer on that link is not accepted, because the OP mentioned that it has strange behaviours. Also there is no evidence.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not a duplicate. The question asks the same thing and the answers attempt to answer it. If you think the answers are wrong or not useful, downvote them. If you think the question hasn't received enough attention, boost it with a bounty.

Comment: I have tested this example and in this case API with mapping /api/book/{action} was called.

Comment: @aamirlatif wow really? were they really identical? headers and etc? because in my tests the so called "more specific url" is being called.

Comment: Sorry my bad. @Spring you are right in this case more specific url is called